# Grouping and sorting results in mysql (data with hierarchical info)

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing items, some being children of others (I would say much like some kind of forum conversation, some are child of previous ones, some have no child, some have many children but there is only one level deep, there are no children of children), for example I get the following list after querying with some criteria, sorted by id's:

```
| id  | title | date       | childof |
| 002 | tit2  | 2017-02-23 | 000     | if 000, not a child
| 003 | tit3  | 2017-05-12 | 000     | not a child
| 004 | tit4  | 2017-03-25 | 002     | child of 002
| 005 | tit5  | 2017-03-26 | 002     | other child of 002
| 006 | tit6  | 2017-06-13 | 000     | not a child
| 007 | tit7  | 2017-07-06 | 003     | only child of 003
```

My question is about sorting/grouping the results: I would like to have the results listed as follow:

```
| id  | title | date       | childof |
| 006 | tit6  | 2017-06-13 | 000     | no child most recent at first level
| 003 | tit3  | 2017-05-12 | 000     | one child
| 007 | tit7  | 2017-07-06 | 003     | only child of previous
| 002 | tit2  | 2017-02-23 | 000     | two children
| 004 | tit4  | 2017-03-25 | 002     | child #1 of 002 oldest
| 005 | tit5  | 2017-03-26 | 002     | child #2 of 002 most recent
```

- by date (most recent first) for the first level (items that are not children)
- children being regrouped after their parent whatever their date but ordered with oldest first under the parent

My starting point was something like:

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE somecriteriaok ORDER BY date GROUP BY childof.

Of course I tried much more complicated solutions but cannot seem to achieve the above result so I tried to come up with this question trying to make it simple and clear ... hopefully I succeeded and will get some hints as where to go (excuse my english ...).

Pierre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a bit tricky, you can do it because the hierarchy is only one level deep.  Here is one method, using `join`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t LEFT JOIN
     mytable tp  -- parent
     ON tp.id = t.childof
WHERE somecriteriaok
ORDER BY COALESCE(tp.date, t.date) DESC,  -- newest parents first
         COALESCE(tp.id, t.id),           -- keep records together
         (tp.id IS NULL) DESC,            -- put the parent first
         t.date;                          -- children in date order
```

Comment: Waou. Properly nailed down !! Didn't know that COALESCE ... so using GROUP BY was not the solution, thanks for the quick answer, I already put it in my otherwise complex request and it works !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a multiple order by?

```
ORDER BY date DESC, childof DESC
```

and maybe add a GROUP BY after that?

Comment: Yes I tried, pbm being that sorting by childof is not relevant, I need to sort by date of items having the same childof, and they need to be listed after their parent with date potentially older than the followning parent;